# How do I build a dynamic string based on user selection?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I allow the user to select a filter which will be used for an SQL query Where clause. He has to pick checkboxes, for example:

```
CreateDate 
User
Nummer
Id
```

I keep variables for each of them:

```
Dim CreateDate as String = "CreateDate >= 2017-08-01"
Dim User as String = "John"
Dim Nummer as String = "789"
Dim Id as String = "1"
```

Let's say user selects User, Nummer and Id. This should construct the following string output:

```
Dim finalWhereString as String = "CreateDate >= 2017-08-01 And User = John And Id = 1"
```

The tricky part for me is to correctly concatenate the strings. How do I add an "And" clause in the correct place between the strings?

Comment: What is so tricky about it? SELECT * From Table_Name WHERE Column1 = '" & variable & "' AND ......  I assume you know how many variables your user will enter.  If not just build it using a bunch of If ElseIF statements.

Comment: depends what user selects, is there anything else besides a lot of if else?

Comment: Not really, you would have to check each condition to see whether or not you have to add to your query.

Answer (score 1):

Add `WHERE 1 = 1` to the base query then add `AND` to every selected condition.
And definitely use `SqlParameter` for passing values to sql query.

```
public class Condition
{
    public Func<bool> IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public SqlParameter Value { get; set; }
}

var conditions = new[]
{
    new Condition
    { 
        IsSelected = () => checkBoxDate.Checked,
        Text = "CreateDate >= @CreatedDate",
        Value = new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", new DateTime(2017, 8, 1))
    },
    new Condition
    { 
        IsSelected = () => checkBoxUser.Checked,
        Text = "User = @User",
        Value = new SqlParameter("@User", "John")
    },
    new Condition
    { 
        IsSelected = () => checkBoxNumber.Checked,
        Text = "Number = @Number",
        Value = new SqlParameter("@Number", 789)
    },
    new Condition
    { 
        IsSelected = () => checkBoxId.Checked,
        Text = "Id = @Id",
        Value = new SqlParameter("@Id", 12)
    }
} 

var selectedConditions = conditions.Where(condition => condition.IsSelected()).ToList();


var baseQuery = "SELECT Id, Number, User, CreatedDate FROM MyTable WHERE 1 = 1";
var parameters = selectedConditions.Select(condition => condition.Value);
var commandText = 
    selectedConditions.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                                 (text, condition) => 
                                 { 
                                     text.Append(" AND ");
                                     text.Append(condition.Text);
                                     return text;
                                 },
                                 (text) => 
                                 {
                                     text.Insert(0, baseQuery);
                                     return text.ToString();
                                 });

using (var connnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
    connection.Open();

    // execute command        
}
```

As @jmoreno suggest you can do it without adding `WHERE 1 = 1` to the query. Then sql building will look like code below - choose approach you think suit better your requirements.

```
var baseQuery = "SELECT Id, Number, User, CreatedDate FROM MyTable";
var selectedText = selectedConditions.Select(condition => condition.Text);
var commandText = 
    selectedConditions.Any() 
        ? $"{baseQuery} WHERE {string.Join(" AND ", selectedText)}" 
        : baseQuery;
```

Comment: using Any and string.join would allow leaving out the WHERE 1=1.

Comment: @jmoreno, correct, this is was what I thought about first, but with `Where 1= 1` code become more straight forward.

Comment: I don't see how.  `string whereClause = !selectedConditions.Any ? "" : "WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", selectedConditions.Select(c=> c.Text)); commandText = baseQuery + whereClause;`.

Comment: @jmoreno, by _straight forward_ I mean no extra `if else` statements - little bid easy to read/follow code.